# iReport java heap space

Tags: java

I'm working on iReport 2.0.4,and when I put an sql statement to get the data i start to get this error :

```
Error filling print... java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded null 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 
Print was not filled. Try using an EmptyDataSource...
```

and Error: Java heap space.

Does anybody have any clue on how I can solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the heap size that you are using now?

Comment: sorry but how i can know that?

Comment: when you run your application, JVM allocates heap space. Please go through here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html

Answer (score 2):

open

```
iReportInstallationDir/etc/ireport.conf
```

change `-J-Xms` &  `-J-Xmx` value according to your system resources

```
default_options="--branding ireport -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m  -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000"
```

Comment: actually i could not find this file on the installation Directory

Comment: @ama its in etc dir which is in installation dir double check it must be there

Comment: i have found this
java -cp "%IREPORT_CLASSPATH%" -Direport.home="%IREPORT_HOME%" -Djava.security.policy="%IREPORT_HOME%/policy.all" -Xms128m -Xmx512m it.businesslogic.ireport.gui.MainFrame %* 



        in startup.bat

Comment: @ama increase  `-Xms128m`, `-Xmx512m`  according to your resource of system

Comment: i have put it like this 
java -cp "%IREPORT_CLASSPATH%" -Direport.home="%IREPORT_HOME%" -Djava.security.policy="%IREPORT_HOME%/policy.all" -Xms512m -Xmx1024m it.businesslogic.ireport.gui.MainFrame %* but nothing changed,still get the same error

Comment: @ama then it is not probably reading conf. from there, there must be conf file as i mentioned please search for it

Answer (score 0):

Solution..
I Using ireport 5.6.0 tools and my report name is OPTAB.jrxml.

1. Right click on ***OPTAB*** in Report Inspector.
2. select **Edit query.**

3.Type "***select 1 from dual" in Report query***.

4.press **Ok**.

now see **field** in your Report Inspector it only contain 1.

Now run you report.

I hope This will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem margins were established for pages, by reducing the size of the first sheet solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error with JDK 1.6 when i use Times New Roman font. With JDK 1.7 fix my problem.